# why unable to concatenate two arrays in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays

```
>>> array1.shape
(97, 195)
>>> array2.shape
(195,)
>>> array1 = numpy.concatenate((array1, array2), axis=0)
```

when I perform concatenate operation it shows an error

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

is that the second array shape `(195,)` creating problem?

Comment: Transpose second array. From docs.scipy: `The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis (the first, by default)`. It should be `(1,195)`. Than you can concatenate over 2nd dimension, obv

Comment: That's not a transpose, but you do want to reshape the array to `(1, 195)`.

Comment: Excuse me? Does `(195,)` array have size `195*0`?

Comment: @s0upa1t: It's not a row vector or a column vector; it's 1-dimensional. Ask NumPy to transpose it (with `transpose` or `T`), and you'll find no change.

Comment: @user2357112, just checked. You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just make both have the same dimensions and the same size except along the axis to be concatenated:

```
np.concatenate((array1, array2[np.newaxis,...]), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you need array2 to actually be 2d.

```
array1 = numpy.concatenate((array1, array2.reshape((1,195)))
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to achieve the array concatenation that you’re looking for is to use Numpy’s `vstack` function as follows:

```
array1 = np.vstack([array1, array2])
```